# Authentication Exception while using Facebook Graph API in C#

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

We want to post on user's Facebook wall from a web or mobile without asking Login. Once we authorize the user through our app then in any case after that user don't have to give credentials. Using Authorized Tokens after authentication we will post on user's wall from code behind automatically. (exactly like Hootsuite is doing)

There are two issues in this case -

1) To add permission on the Facebook application for "publish_actions" - The issue is whenever we put information on Facebook App and put it in a review. It gives us message against Views/Notes section saying -

"It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

2) Whenever we tried to make posts using the AppID and Secret through Graph API code, in return we get message saying -

"OAuthException (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Note : We are coding in ASP.net using C# to create a webservice which can be used for mobile platform as well as web platform, We have also tried Facebook Javascript SDK to perform the same task but case 2 happens when we make call.

So, please suggest solutions for it.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before you publish your facebook app you have to test it, there is a way to activate this "test session". Only after that facebook will allow you to publish your app at dismiss the message "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

For the second point, maybe I misunderstood, but there is no way to publish content on a wall without the "client" give the authorization. So you must login and get the token to be allowed to do that.

But, I think that if the first point is correct, the 2nd will be working

Comment: Hi Thanks for your prompt response. So, How can I test it without allowing permission settings. Should I create test app?

Comment: Yes, on your left facebook menu you have "Test Apps", there you can do that

Comment: Actually, I have already created the "Test App" but we havn't used it and that test app doesn't have all set of permissions what a Live App have.

Comment: Hi, The latest "Test App" is not showing Live Status.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you, using scope in the login url [facebook scope](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2?locale=fr_FR)